# Catalogue vs. Search option in WordPress WooCommerce, which option is the best for my websites ranking?

Tags: seo, wordpress, woocommerce

In a Wordpress WooCommerce website, I can choose 'catalogue or search or both' for my products.

If a product has been sold, which option is the best for my websites ranking in search engines and Why? Side note: I do not wish to select 'out of stock' for any of my products.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not to opt both of these. However, If you enable search by default and don't showcase your products in proper hierarchy then visitors will not bother to be on your site. Especially when it comes to E-commerce businesses. So Catalog is the best option to opt.